# How to inject a Bean in xml from a method (@Bean) which returns an Interface (com.typesafe.config.Config)?

Tags: spring, dependency-injection, spring-java-config, spring-bean, typesafe-config

I have an xml-config-based spring application where one of my beans requires as constructor parameter a com.typesafe.config.Config parameter. 
For that purpose we have a @Configuration class where one of the methods (annotated as @Bean) returns a com.typesafe.config.Config object.

But when spring starts it complains that "Failed to instantiate [com.typesafe.config.Config]: Specified class is an interface"

How do I inject the getconfig return object into the constructor via xml ?

Here is the code snippet simplified to get rid of application logic:

```
import com.typesafe.config.Config;
...
public class myFilter implements Filter {
  public myFilter(Config aconfig) {
        ...
  }
}
```

Then I have a JavaConfig class as follows that creates the bean I need to inject in the myFilter constructor:

```
@org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration
public class TSConfiguration {
   ...
   @Bean(name = "app-config")
   public Config getConfig() {
     ...
   }
}
```

I've put in my spring.xml file the following:

```
<beans:bean class="TSConfiguration" />
<beans:bean id="app-config" class="com.typesafe.config.Config"/>
<beans:bean id="theFilter" class="myFilter">
   <beans:constructor-arg index="0" ref="app-config"/>
 </beans:bean>
```

Here is the Exception from Spring:

```
15-Feb-2017 13:19:55.463 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext Context initialization failed
 org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'app-config' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring-security.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.typesafe.config.Config]: Specified class is an interface
```

Thanx.

Answer (score 1):

The offending line is this:

`<beans:bean id="app-config" class="com.typesafe.config.Config"/>`

Since you've put this in your *spring.xml*, Spring is trying to instantiate a bean called `app-config` from `Config`. But `Config` is an interface, so Spring is unable to instantiate it and hence the error.

I think, once you remove it, Spring will pick the `@Bean` you instantiated using `getConfig`. If that doesn't work, see if `TSConfiguration` is properly getting imported into you *spring.xml*.

Comment: I tried to remove it , but still doesn't work. removing that bean definition line I got 
Cannot resolve reference to bean 'app-config' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'app-config' is defined

Comment: I did not get any error from the TSConfiguration  bean .

Comment: I did not get any error from the TSConfiguration  bean: removing the myFilter bean definition with requires the app-config, no other Exceptions are thrown. I left in TSConfiguration and no error in given.

Comment: I think your original question is answered. This next one- it depends on how you are importing one config to another. Can you update that? Also, why can't you instantiate myFilter inside TSConfiguration? That'd be simpler

Comment: The question was "How do I inject the getconfig return object into the constructor via xml ?". I did not find a solution yet. TSConfiguration is part of a module shared along other webapps while my Filter needs to be instanciated from the existing xml in this webapp to get the typesafe Config.

Answer (score 0):

To add to the other answer, you are declaring what is probably intended to be the same bean twice.

Here, you are telling Spring to create a bean of Config type with the name `app-config`:

```
 @Bean(name = "app-config")
 public Config getConfig(){
```

Here, you are trying to create another bean of type `Config` with the id `app-config`.

```
 <beans:bean id="app-config" class="com.typesafe.config.Config"/>
```

If you declare a bean in JavaConfig, it is not necessary to declare it again in XML and vice versa (Assuming your intention is to have a single bean of that type).

And, as it was already pointed out, you cannot instantiate an interface.

---

Updated:

I'm going to basically half-way ignore the code you posted, as there seems to be a misunderstanding of what the annotations do and how to use them.

First off, if you want to do everything in pure XML, you can't do this:

```
<beans:bean id="app-config" class="com.typesafe.config.Config"/>
```

You need to make a concrete implementation of that interface. But, based on what you posted, you have a configuration class you're using. Let's start with that:

```
package com.testpackage;

@Configuration
public class Config {


        @Bean
        public SomeInterface someImplementation(){
            return new SomeInterface() {
                @Override
                public String implementation() {
                    return "String";
                }
            };
        }
    }
```

This says create a bean of type `SomeInterface`. The name of this bean will inherit the method name, `someImplementation`, so there's no point in giving it a name manually. Note that, while this is returning an interface, we are creating an anonymous class and returning that.

Next, we'll take a look at the XML for the above:

```
<beans>
        <context:component-scan base-package="com.testpackage"/>

        <bean class="com.testpackage.ConcreteClass">
            <constructor-arg index="0" ref="someImplementation"/>
        </bean>
</beans>
```

Notice we are scanning (`context:component-scan`) the package with  with the configuration in it. If we're using the `@Configuration` annotation, we can do a component scan.

The example below does the same thing but just manually declares the Configuration bean:

```
<beans>
        <bean class="com.testpackage.Config"/>

        <bean class="com.testpackage.ConcreteClass">
            <constructor-arg index="0" ref="someImplementation"/>
        </bean>
</beans>
```

If you manually declare the Config class like above, **you do not need to annotate it with `@Configuration`**. The point of that annotation is for a component scan to "see" the bean and instantiate it. Since we're doing it manually, the annotation is not required.

And, for the sake of completeness, this is a unit test that verifies everything works:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {"classpath:META-INF/appContextTest.xml"})
public class SomeTester {


    @Autowired
    ConcreteClass concreteClass;

    @Test
    public void test(){
        assertEquals("String", concreteClass.impl.implementation());
    }
}
```

Comment: Followng spring JavaConfig docs http://docs.spring.io/spring-javaconfig/docs/1.0.0.m3/reference/html/creating-bean-definitions.html the bean should be declared in xml. Moreover in the Component scanning the @Bean is not intended to be detected auto instanciated.

Comment: The intention is to use in xml bean definition a bean defined with JavaConfig. Following this guide http://docs.spring.io/spring-javaconfig/docs/1.0.0.m3/reference/html/creating-bean-definitions.html (with few updates related to the removal of ConfigurationPostProcessor) I'm hitting the problem.  I'm trying to declare it because it does not get automatically inject and need to pass to the myFilter constructor.

Comment: There is nothing in that documentation that says it should be in both XML and JavaConfig. It should not be in both spots. Your question is a bit unclear at this point. You should make a new one with a full example of the problem you're trying to solve. Your existing question has been answered correctly.

Comment: The question was "How do I inject the getconfig return object into the constructor via xml ?" I don't think it has been answered. It has been suggested to remove the offending line in previous answer, I tried, but it still doesn't work. What is the question answered?

Comment: I guess you're right. Truthfully, you've got multiple issues in the code you've provided, so there's no guarantee you've not done other things wrong (Mainly, you are heavily mixing Java Config and XML that does the same thing twice). I'll update my answer with a basic example.